# Dirac delta distribution, one after another

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

It is well-known that one cannot, in general, multiply distributions. In particular, it is not clear what does it mean to define a [square delta distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere). However, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876869/two-dirac-delta-functions-in-an-integral), expressions like:
\begin{equation}
\int dz \delta(x-z)\delta(y-z) = \delta(x-y) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
have mathematical meaning.

When I learned distributions, I remember that the Dirac delta was defined as follows. Take a smooth function $f$ on $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and fix $x \in \Omega$. Then the Dirac delta distribution $\delta_{x}$ is the distribution defined by:
$$\langle \delta_{x},f\rangle := f(x) \tag{2}\label{2}$$
The right hand side of (\ref{2}) is a number, so it does not make sense to apply a new Dirac delta to this object. However, we can think of $f$ itself as a function $\Omega \ni x \mapsto  g(x) :=\langle\delta_{x},f\rangle \equiv f(x)$, so it would make sense to think of:
$$\langle \delta_{y},g\rangle = f(y)\tag{3}\label{3}$$

Relation (\ref{3}) seems to be well-defined as, although it differs from applying the Dirac delta again in (\ref{2}), the difference seems sutile.

I want to know: is (\ref{3}) what is really going on in (\ref{1})? I think the integral representation of the Dirac delta ends up making manipulations easier, but I wanted to give meaning to (\ref{1}) by using the Dirac delta as usually is done in distribution theory courses (as far as I know, the integral representation of the delta is more common in the physics literature).

Comment: are you missing a $\delta(\cdot)$ in the integral?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, now fixed.

Comment: What's the difference between $f$ and $g$? Aren't they equal?

Comment: Yes. Just to make the notations clearer.

Comment: [Distributions can be multiplied](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+of+distributions) as long as their **wavefront sets** satisfy some some non-intersection property (cf. [Hörmander's criterion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/H%C3%B6rmander%27s+criterion)).